# Auto Sign-in Firebase user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I need help with my code. Here is the code linking to my loginviewcontroller and pretty much I can't find anywhere on the Internet explaining this. I am trying to make it so that the first time the user logs in, they are always logged in until they sign out so then the user doesn't have to keep on signing in every time they open the app. I've tried keychain and all of that but I couldn't figure it out. What am I missing? I got rid of the garbage code that tried to save the info.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pwField: UITextField!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser == nil {
            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login") as! UsersViewController
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: Any) {
         guard emailField.text != "", pwField.text != "" else {return}

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: pwField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            if user != nil {
                let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "centralvc")

                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest checking if the user is logged in on the main screen, and in case he isn't display the login view controller.

Now to check if a user is signed in, I recommend calling Firebase's currentUser method rather than checking with CoreData or UserDefaults because you might be signed in on the device but the UID of the user changed. I will not go in depth on how to implement Firebase's methods, but you can see all of them here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start

Answer (score 0):

Move everything from viewWillAppear to viewDidAppear